# IRAs for US citizens who are non-US residents

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, non-resident, expatriate

I am a US citizen residing in the UK (for the long term). I understand that I can legally invest in a Roth IRA; however, it seems very difficult to actually open one that will allow me to do so with a foreign address as a primary residence. (I think this is due to PFIC/FATCA reporting requirements, among other things.)

So: any advice on finding one that does allow us to invest from here?

Comment: Don't you have a US address with friends or family you could use?

Comment: @littleadv of course, but that strikes as me as likely against both the letter and the spirit of the relevant rules. Is that a problem?

Comment: I'm not aware of any rules that forbid expats from having IRAs. It's just the convenience of the brokers.

Comment: PFIC and FATCA apply only to non-US _assets_ (companies and accounts respectively) and IRAs can't be non-US, because only approved US institutions (banks and similar) are permitted to operate them. There is a special (US) withholding requirement for IRA distribution to a non-US address, although I'd expect that to be less of an issue with Roth than with traditional. And there may be withholding or other compliance requirements imposed by (at least some) residence countries that the US institution doesn't want to deal with, but I don't know any specifics.

Comment: To be clear, if you _directly_ hold non-US including UK accounts or investments, pretty much a practical necessity when living there, you must report those to IRS under PFIC and FATCA _and_ to FinCEN under BSA (FBAR).

Comment: Yes, I think the point is that the PFIC/PATCA requirements seem to have made most US-based brokerages much more wary of accepting foreign addresses, as I understand it.